# Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two (NSDate?) operators

Tags: sum, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Trying to get a total amount of time from a start time and end time.

I have the DateFormatter correct as in Extension.swift below but I am getting confused on the way to calculate bottomtime - starttime.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Extension.swift

```
extension NSDate{
var bottomtimestringValue: String{
    return self.toString()
}

func tobottomtimeString() -> String {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd"
    let str = formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    return str
}
}

extension String{
var bottomtimedateValue: NSDate?{
    return self.toDate()
}

func tobottomtimeDate() -> NSDate? {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MMM-dd"
    if let date = formatter.dateFromString(self) {
        return date
    }else{
        // if format failed, Put some code here
        return nil // an example
    }
}
}
```

Adddivelogviewcontroller.swift

```
var a = (textFieldStartTime.text.starttimedateValue)
    var b = (textFieldEndTime.text.endtimedateValue)
    var sum = b - a
    textFieldBottomTime.text = "\(sum)"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct-- the `-` operator is not defined for `NSDate?`, so you can't find the difference that way. Since `a` and `b` are both `NSDate?`, you could find the difference like this:

```
if let dateA = a, dateB = b {
    let difference = dateA.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - dateB.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
}
```

Here, `difference`'s type will be `NSTimeInterval?`.

Or if you prefer, you could add a definition of `-` for `NSDate?`, which might look like this:

```
func -(lhs:NSDate?, rhs:NSDate?) -> NSTimeInterval? {
    if let left=lhs, right=rhs {
        return left.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - right.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Add that and you can use `-` above.

Answer (score -1):

OK, not really sure if thats working or not but i get no errors.  What I need this to do calculate after the end time picker OK botton is pressed

```
func OK3ButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.textFieldEndTime.endEditing(true)
    self.textFieldEndTime.text = endtimePickerView.date.endtimestringValue

    var a = (textFieldStartTime.text.starttimedateValue)
    var b = (textFieldEndTime.text.endtimedateValue)
  var difference: String = ""
  if let dateA = a, dateB = b {
    let difference = dateA.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - dateB.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
  }
  textFieldBottomTime.text = "\(difference)"       
}
```